# Can a process update a shared queue while threads consume the queue?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

I'm trying to create a multithreaded hash cracker/bruteforcer in Python and I'm encountering an issue when having a thread generate all possible word combinations and put them on a queue while having 10 other threads hash the queue. The issue is that the 10 hashing threads hog execution time from the 1 thread generator, bottlenecking it. So my question is this: Is it possible to have a process update a queue that can be used by other threads concurrently in Python?

Comment: Yes - see the docs for `multiprocessing.Queue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [multiprocessing.Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) object is process and thread safe.

I'd let the main loop of your solution populate the Queue while multiple processes hash its content.

As you work seems to be CPU bound, I'd avoid threads.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was having a for loop with a put call to load the words and a get call to take each word and hash.  This resulted in ~2,000,000-12,000,000 get and put call making locking of the queue constant and my program horribly slow. Now I'm storing 500,000 words in a `bytearray` resulting in a ridiculous speed improvement